# Error while installing Weblogic in windows 10

Tags: oracle, windows-10, weblogic, executable-jar

While installing the Weblogic in windows 10  using jar file, I am getting the error message as **Unable to access or modify the system registry.  Select Run as Administrator when opening the Command Prompt and try again.** though am executing as Administrator. From the log file I got the below error.

**WARNING [1] com.oracle.cie.common.jni.WinRegistryHelper - Create Key Failed: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle

2017-10-06 11:19:54,972 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.PlatformHelper - createRegistry to add a value failed

2017-10-06 11:19:54,972 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - Unable to access or modify the system registry.  Select Run as Administrator when opening the Command Prompt and try again.**

I understood that on making the System Registry entry **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle**, it is failing because the same entry already exists in my system as *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE*. Though system registry is case-insensitive, weblogic is failing on making entries to this registry. Is there any solution to overcome this? The same issue has been already posted in different sites but not yet answered.Any help to solve this issue will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the next lines works  to solve the problem.

1. Open cmd like administrator.
2. `java -d64 -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar`  If you don't have correctly configured the `JAVA_HOME`, you can replace the word "java", for the path where you have installed de JDK. Something like this:

   ```
   C:\JRockit\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe
   ```